# RDP: Prevent Windows from moving my windows when they are positioned slightly off screen

Tags: rdp

This question is very specific to the situation where I position the Windows partially off-screen.  Like this:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

After I disconnect and reconnect to the RDP session, the Windows are moved so that the boundaries are within the borders.  I would like to avoid this.  Is that possible?

This problem occurs in:

Windows 10 /
Windows Server 2019 /
Windows Server 2016 /
Windows Server 2012